# SonarQube plugin for R language

Tags: r, plugins, sonarqube

I was looking for a SonarQube plugin to analyze R code but I haven't found.
will it be implemented in the next future?

Thanks.

Comment: This would something to ask the developers of the plugin. We would have no clue what they're thinking.

Comment: have you any news on this ?

Comment: No, I was hoping for some SonarSource member's response!

Comment: There is [sonar-r-plugin](https://github.com/Merck/sonar-r-plugin). Currently, I am working on applying it with TeamCity